# Metadata question/ Netmix question

Tags: metadata

I am trying to figure out where/ what field the track info is stored in.  I can see and modify that information in Wave agent, but do not see it in pro tools until I drop a file into the session and split into mono tracks.  I do not see any of that information in Netmix.

I am trying to simplify some of my library material.  Instead of having a handful of mono files which are different perspectives of the same material Close/Mid/Far/Really far, It would be nice to have them as a poly file with the metadata reflecting what each channel is.

Anyone know which fields that information is stored and if it is something that netmix can read/write back into the .wav file.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: hi michael, can you explain the differences between soundminer and netmix? i can't find a demo so cannot test it myself..

Comment: Not really sure of all the differences.  Two different programs for sound effects database management.